# create seam 3 project

Tags: seam, seam3

i'm new in seam3 and i've googled to find that how it possible to create a seam3 project in netbeans/eclipse, but i have not found a good tutorial yet. so please help me to solve this issue. also in your opinion which IDE is better with seam?
thanks.

Comment: So, have you fixed your problem ?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the Maven archetype to start a new project : http://seamframework.org/Documentation/CDIQuickstartForMavenUsers

Answer (score 0):

Still there is no IDE support for seam3, but you can use seam forge to get started.